# Необходимо определить радиус и центр окружности

Tags: c++

задача написать код на c++, чтобы определить радиус и центр окружности, на которой лежит наибольшее число точек заданного на плоскости массива точек A(xi,yi).
Не знаю даже как подступиться к написанию кода, буду благодарен, если кто-то сможет объяснить с чего мне следует начать в решении этой задачи или как должны работать функции.

Comment: Нужна ли программисту геометрия? Конечно, нет.

Comment: Если совсем в лоб: перебирать все комбинации точек по три, для каждой находить центр круга и радиус, а потом смотреть, какие центр+радиус встретились чаще всего.

Comment: Задачка какая-то простая. центр = (0,0) радиус = ∞

Comment: самый простой вариант, который я знаю - найти максимальные и минимальные значения по x и y координате. теперь, скомбинирован их попарно, можно получить 4 точки ограничивающего прямоугольника. Очевидно, что диагональ - хороший кандидат на диаметр.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Так ведь "на окружности" и "в круге" - две большие разницы...

Comment: ага, я уже прочитал...